# NSIS variable not allowed space in define variable

Tags: nsis

```
 **define POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "C:\Program Files\Postgre SQL\9.3"**
```

NSIS varible not allowed space in below declared variable.

```
[INFO] [MAKENSIS] DetailPrint expects 1 parameters, got 2.
[INFO] [MAKENSIS] Usage: DetailPrint message
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:nsis-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile (64bit_REACH) on project dsr.installer: Execution of makensis compiler failed. See output above for details. -> [Help 1]
```

It works fine if i define variable without space like:

```
 `**define POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.3"**`
```

But i want space between the declared variable like

```
`**define POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "C:\Program Files\Postgre SQL\9.3"**`
```

So please let me know how to execute this defined variable.

Comment: What you are asking is somewhat unclear.

Comment: When i added the variable in code define POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3" then i got the compilation failure message. Please let me know how to execute this variable.

Comment: You are talking about a define, not a variable...

Comment: You should use "$ProgramFiles\..." and not hardcode "C:\Program Files\..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is telling you the problem, the `DetailPrint` instruction takes 1 parameter and when a string with spaces is not quoted correctly it will be interpreted as multiple parameters.

```
!define POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3"

Section
;DetailPrint ${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY} ; This will not work because the string is not quoted
DetailPrint "${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY}"
DetailPrint '${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY}'
DetailPrint "Hello ${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY} World"
DetailPrint 'Hello "${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY}" World'
DetailPrint "Hello $\"${POSTGRESQL_INSTALLATION_DIRECTORY}$\" World"
SectionEnd
```